# Sharepoint Web Service Query

Tags: sharepoint, service, web, caml

I'm creating an iOS app that queries a Sharepoint Webservice with GetListItems.  I'm able to retrieve all of the records, but there are a lot of records > 4000.  Is there a way I can retrieve 50 at a time?

I'm using SOAP for this by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're passing a CAML query to the webservice, you ca use a rowlimit tag

```
<Query>
   <!-- your current query here -->
   <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
</Query>
```

**EDIT**

To retrieve a subset of values you could do something like this

```
<Query>
   <Where>
     <And>
       <Geq>
         <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
         <Value Type='Counter'>0</Value>
       </Geq>
       <Lt>
         <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
         <Value Type='Counter'>100</Value>
       </Lt>
     </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.  Of course, you're going to want to change the values in your code to retrieve the particular subset.

Comment: True, but then how do I get the next 100 rows?

Comment: I dont think there's a way to do that with CAML.  One way you could do this is to limit the returned rows by using a where statement returning rows based on the row ID.  Something like where ID >= 0 and ID < 100.  Next time, you get ID >= 100 and ID < 200.  You may not get exactly 10 rows each time, but you'll get them all eventually. Obviously, you'd need to write it in CAML.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to do this like your code above?

Comment: Hmmmm.. doesn't seem to work.  I always get the first 30 values no matter what I set the counters to (30 is the default number of values on a page)

Comment: If you set the query to look for number 200 to 300, do you still only get the first 30 (numbers 1 to 31), or do you get 200 to 230?

Comment: Now I get errors.  I read that you have to wrap it in a <query> </query> (note the lowercase q).  These are soap calls btw.  The error I get is a SoapServerException

Comment: Figured it out. It should be Value Type and not Value type (case sensitive).  Do you know where I can find documentation on this?  I find I'm guessing half the time

Comment: SharePoint caml is confusing.  There used to be a really good website that laid out how to create queries and had very good samples.  I cannot find it anymore, but there's one at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ms467521.aspx that's pretty thorough.  Here's another with some samples: http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/caml-query-tutorial-for-sharepoint.html. In this regard, Google is your friend.  Don't forget to mark this as an answer if you found it answered your problem.